# Combine two similar rows into one with new columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Original table:

```
Name         Age      Contact_type   Contact
Alex         20       SMS            12345
Alex         20       Email          abc@gmail.com
Alex         20       SMS            54321
Bob          35       SMS            23456
```

I want to make it as:

```
Name          Age     Contact_type1   Contact_1  Contact_type2  Contact_2       Contact_type3 Contact_3
Alex          20           SMS          12345        Email     abc@gmail.com        SMS          23456
Bob           35           SMS          23456
```

If name and age are duplicated, combine the 2(or more) rows into 1 row with new column as shown above.

I want to do that by finding the same 'Name' and 'Age', and using DISTINCT CONTACT like `case when count distinct(contact)>0` but it seems so many syntax error occur. Is there any smarter method to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conditional Aggregate` to do this

```
select Name,Age,
       max(case when Contact = 'SMS' then Contact end) as Contact_1,
       max(case when Contact = 'Email' then Contact end) as Contact_2
from yourtable
group by Name, Age
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well in this case. But what if the table becomes more complicated as the edited question?

Comment: then its a new question